# Hibernate Criteria limit select

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

So, I have a rather complex query I am trying to make using the Hibernate Criteria API. I have the following entity classes:

> Code
>   Gift
>   GiftVendor
>   GiftVendorStatus

with the following relationships:

> Code 1<>1 Gift
>   Gift 1<>* GiftVendor
>   GiftVendor 1<>1 GiftVendorStatus

I need to build a Criteria query that returns a List of Code objects, but that restricts it to only Codes that have a Gift that have at least one GiftVendor with a GiftVendorStatus of Online. Here is the code I am using to build the criteria:

```
Criteria base = CodeDao.getBaseCriteria();
base.createAlias("gift","gift");
base.createAlias("gift.giftVendor","giftVendor");
base.createAlias("giftVendor.giftVendorStatus","giftVendorStatus");
base.add(Restrictions.like("giftVendorStatus.description", "Online%"));
return base.list();
```

This gives me a List of Code objects, restricted as I would expect. However, it also does additional queries to build out all of the unused relationships of the Gift object, even though I have all of the mappings set up with a fetch mode of Lazy. This results in 4 additional, separate queries for each of my 10000+ results.

I have code to do the query using HQL that works as expected:

```
String hql = "select c FROM Code c inner join c.gift g inner join g.giftVendors gv inner join gv.giftVendorStatus gvs" +
    " WHERE gvs.description like :desc";
HashMap<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("desc", "Online%");
return performQuery(hql, params);
```

That code gives me a List of Code objects, as expected, without doing all of the extra queries to populate the Gift object. How do I tell Hibernate not to do those extra queries with the Criteria API?

UPDATE: The problem here is not the retrieval of the Gift table, but rather unrelated one-to-one relationships from the Gift table. For example, Gift has a one-to-one relationship to GiftCommentAggregateCache. This table is in no way related to this particular query, so I would expect lazy initialization rules to apply, and the query to GiftCommentAggregateCache to not occur unless a read is attempted. However, with the Criteria query written out as above, it makes that separate query to populate the model object for GiftCommentAggregateCache.

If I use:

```
base.setFetchMode("gift.giftCommentAggregateCache", FetchMode.JOIN);
```

then I do not have any problems. However, that means that in order for this to work as I would expect, I need to add that line for every single unused one-to-one relationship that Gift has. Any ideas as to why the Lazy rules specified in the mappings are not coming into play here?

There are a few different things I have tried:

```
base.setFetchMode("gift", FetchMode.LAZY); // Still does additional queries
```

and

```
base.setFetchMode("gift", FetchMode.SELECT); // Still does additional queries
```

and

```
base.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY); // Still does additional queries
```

and

```
base.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ROOT_ENTITY); // Still does additional queries
```

and

```
base.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP); // Still does additional queries
```

and

```
base.setProjection(Projections.property("gift")); // Does not do additional queries, but incorrectly returns a List of Gift objects, instead of a List of Code objects
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching):

> Join fetching: Hibernate retrieves the associated instance or collection in the same SELECT, using an OUTER JOIN.

In other words, try using base.setFetchMode("gift", FetchMode.JOIN)

I hope that helps.

Cheers

Comment: While the specific suggestion specified here did not fix things up, it did point me in the right direction for how to fix the problem. I updated my question with the new results. However, this still doesn't seem right, as I have to add that line for all one-to-one mappings from my Gift object, when the default mappings should apply here.